# How can I invoke javascript functions from a wkwebview?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview

I'm using a `wkwebview` and when the user tap inside, I need to send back to the web server informations to allow it to make some actions :

The first function called `btDialogClicked("ok" / "cancel")` which is inside my completion handler action sheet alert :

```
Extension.createActionSheet(title: body["title"], message: body["message"], validationMessage: body["buttonOK"], cancelMessage: body["buttonCancel"], controller: self, completionHandler: nil)
```

And the second inside my case called `btBackClicked` which is inside the back case of my enum :

```
case .back:
backButton.imageView?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrow_left")
break
```

How can I implement these two.

Answer (score 1):

`evaluateJavaScript()` will allow you to run any JavaScript on webpage loaded by you WebView. Like:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('myJSTextField').innerText") { (result, error) in
    guard error == nil, let result = result else {
       print("Error!")
    }
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Apple documentation for this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript